# Jenkins Multi-branch Unable to find project artifact copy

Tags: jenkins, compiler-errors, multibranch-pipeline

I am using `multibranch-pipeline`, I need to connect 3 upstream branches in signal down stream branch. When I tried to copy artifacts from upstream project, I got the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: http://servername/job/pocbranches/test
> This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
> Finished: FAILURE

Below code is for my down stream branch.

```
copyArtifacts fingerprintArtifacts: true,
projectName:'$projectName',
selector: upstream()
```

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using absolute filepath

```
copyArtifacts fingerprintArtifacts: true,
projectName: '/' + '$projectName',
selector: upstream()
```

Also give copyArtifact permission like

```
    options {
        copyArtifactPermission('/' + $projectName)
    }
```